# Tangent space for embedded submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

I was reading Lee's smooth manifold book, in page 116 there is a theorem for tangent space for embedded submanifold:

Let $S\subset M$ be embedded $k$ dimension submanifold for $n$ dimension smooth manifold $M$.so we have the smooth inclusion map $i:S\to M$

> We want to show that: if $v\in T_p M$ with $vf = 0$ whenever $f|_S =0$ then $w\in T_pS$ such that $di_p(w) = v$.

Choosing slice chart $(U,\psi)$ as usual,the inclusion map $i:S\bigcap U\to M$ has coordinate representation:$i(x^1,...,x^k) = (x^1,...,x^n)$

Now I know under the standard basis $v\in T_pM$ has the form:
$$v=\left.\sum_{i=1}^{n} v^{i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\right|_{p}$$

$v\in T_p S$ if and only if $v^j = 0$ when $j>k$

the final step is evalute $v$ at function $f(x) = \phi(x)x^j$ at $p$ with $\phi$ a bump function support at $U$ and indentically 1 at neighborhood of $p$,here comes the question for the final step:

> **The questions are two:why we need to use bump function here to construct $f(x) = \phi(x)x^j$ with $j>k$ instead of using $f(x) = x^j$
> directly,and why $f(x)$ vanishes on $S$?**

Comment: The author goes back and forth between directly applying coordinate function $v(x^i)$ and use bump function as $v(\varphi x^i)$ whichever more convenient. When the author allowed to write $v(x^i)$ because he already mentioned that we sometimes identify $T_pM$ with $T_pU$ (see last paragraph on page 56). Although i've seen he uses $v(\varphi x^i)$ more often in the proof.

Comment: @Si Kucing  since $\varphi$ is defined on the whole manifold,but $x^i$ still on the small neighborhood $U$,so function $f = \varphi x^j$ here is actually smooth function only defined on $U$, i.e. $f\in C^\infty (U)$ correct?

Comment: Lee also discusses how to get rid of the bump functions by using a more sophisticated definition for the tangent space, namely as derivations on the germs of functions at $p$, i.e. classes of equivalence of couples $[f,U]$ such that $U$ is an open set of $M$ which contains $p$, $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and $(f,U)\sim(g,V)$ iff there is an open set $W\subset U\cap V$ which contains $p$ and such that $f|_W=g|_W$. With this definition, $C^\infty_p(M)=C^\infty_p(U)$ whenever $U$ is an open set, and you have $T_pU=T_pM$ without any identification needed.

Comment: Yes but we can regard $\varphi x^j$ as a function on the whole manifolds as follows. We have $\varphi x^j : U \to \mathbb{R}$ right? This function vanish outside supp $\varphi$, which is a closed set contained in $U$. Now define new function $g : M \to \mathbb{R}$ as follows $g\equiv 0$ on $M \smallsetminus \text{supp }\varphi$, and $g=\varphi x^j$ on $U$. The function $g$ is smooth by glueing lemma. This new function is still be called $\varphi x^j$ by Lee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is right: with your definition, a tangent vector acts on functions defined on the whole manifold. But, since its action is local, extending a given function by the use of a bump function will still result in the wanted behaviour around the point you are watching.

Your functions $f^j=\varphi\times x^j$, $j>k$, vanishes on whole $S$, because in $U\cap S$, the coordinates $x^j$ $(j>k)$ vanishes, and outside $U$ it is $\varphi$ who does.